# Swift 3: Inheritance from non-named type

Tags: swift, generics, compiler-errors, swift-protocols, associated-types

I have the following SSCIE:

```swift
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Bar
    associatedtype Baz: (Self.Bar) -> Void

    var currentValue: Bar { get }
}
```

That I want to use like this:

```
func call<T: Foo>(foo: T, callback: @escaping T.Baz) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        callback(foo.currentValue)
    }
}
```

But it fails to compile, with the error:

> Inheritance from non-named type '(`Self`.Bar)'

[image: The code in the snippet above, with the error on the second type.]

This also fails to compile  when I use `(Bar) -> Void` and `(Foo.Bar) -> Void`.

---

[Sadly, Googling this didn't come up with any useful results.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Swift+%22inheritance+from+non-named+type%22)

Does anyone have any idea what this error means, what I'm doing wrong, and how to correct it?

Comment: Note that I use the [Fira Code font](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), so `->` _renders_ as `→`, but is _encoded_ as `->`.

Comment: Well you cannot conform to or inherit from `(Bar) -> Void`, so it's not a legal constraint on the associated type.

Comment: @Hamish edited this question to change the [swift3] tag to [swift], but this error was introduced in Swift 3 as per [SR-2843](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2843)

Comment: @Hamish Is there any way to specify a generic function, then? So that I can have a callback whose parameter type is assured?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean regarding the error being introduced in Swift 3 (the bug report you link to is about protocol composition) – AFAIK, it has never been legal to use a function type as an associated type constraint.

Comment: @Hamish I link that bug because it is the motivation behind [PR #5290](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/5290/files), which is the first instance I can find of testing for that error message. I will edit my question to clarify my intent.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "specify a generic function"? Could you show a concrete example of how you were planning on using the protocol `Foo`? Why can't you just have requirement(s) of type `(Bar) -> Void`? The conforming type will still have to satisfy the placeholder `Bar`. Unrelated, but note that the constraint `: Any` is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh okay I see regarding the specific error message being introduced in Swift 3 – but that's mostly irrelevant to your main question of "what I'm doing wrong" anyway, as what you're doing was still illegal in Swift 2, and will likely remain illegal in Swift 4.

Comment: I have added a more complete example

Comment: The `callback:` parameter should just be typed as `(T.Bar) -> Void` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associated types in Swift 3 can only be "is-a"-constrained. So your `Bar` is required to be an `Any`. Which, by the way, is not much of a constraint ;). In other words, you can remove it.

However, `(Self.Bar) -> Void` is a function type and you can't constrain an associated type like this.

If you want to define a callback type, you can use a typealias:

```
protocol Foo
{
    associatedtype Bar
    typealias Callback = (Self.Bar) -> Void

    var currentValue: Bar { get }

    func f(callback: Callback) -> Void
}
```

Using `@escaping` does not currently work in a typealias (see [SR-2316](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2316) and its various duplicates). This is a bug that was supposed to have a fix soon (as of August 2016). So you will have to spell it out for now:

```
func call<T: Foo>(foo: T, callback: @escaping (T.Bar) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        callback(foo.currentValue)
    }
}
```

**Update:** As Hamish suggested, I filed [SR-4967](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4967). I'll update this post as soon as there is any news about it.

Comment: Sweet! But now the error is propegated down; in the `call` function in my example, it says "`@escaping attribute only applies to function types`"

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to add @escaping to a typealias. IIRC, this is a bug. I'll try to look up the SR. For now I'm afraid you might have to spell it out, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I guess we were both typing at the same time :).

Comment: @thm I suspect that the inability to use `@escaping` on a protocol `typealias` is a corner-case which wasn't addressed in the fix for the bug report you link to (I'm running the Swift 4 branch, and still doesn't compile for me). Probably worth opening a new bug report.

Comment: @Hamish Hah, good to know, thanks! Totally forgot to check, I installed a snapshot recently myself :). I'll open a new bug report, then.

Comment: @thm please link the bug when you do so I can upvote and watch it!

Comment: @BenLeggiero Link to the bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4967

Comment: @Hamish I feel a little stalked ;). Joking aside, I filed SR-4967 and then had to leave in a hurry. I updated the post and upvoted the question.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, function types can't be used as associated types.

Try this instead:

```
func call<T: Foo>(foo: T, callback: @escaping (T.Bar) -> Void) {
    ...
}
```

and using this design you can mix-and-match function types (for the `callback` arg) for each specific helper function (`call` in your example) you come up with.